# Perform index-wise matrix operation in julia

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, julia

I want to perform index-wise operation on a matrix. I know that you can write a regular function and perform it on each entry of the matrix e.g.

```
function foo(x::Int64)
    return x * 2
end
myArray = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
foo.(myArray)
```

how would I go about doing something like `x * x.elementCol + x.elementrow`? essentially the following code in parallel:

```
function goo(x::Array{Int64,2})
    for j = 1:size(x,2)  
        for i = 1:size(x,1)
            x[i,j] = (x[i,j] * j) + i    
        end
    end
    return x
end
```

Comment: Note that Julia prefers the loop style, at least it is 3X faster in your case than the vectorized version of DNF. Starting with Julia 0.6, however, things are getting better. Previous versions weren't as good as MATLAB in vectorized code, see for example [This talk by Lindsey Kuper about the Prospect project](https://youtu.be/O6PN-kpbNTw). I hope vectorized code in Julia gets as fast as looped one.

Comment: There is some overhead to the broadcasting version, but for a 100x100 matrix I only get a difference of ~15%.

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
x .= x .* indices(x, 2)' .+ indices(x, 1)
```